# Помогите с масштабированием фотографии в tkinter

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, pillow, resize

Я делаю прогу для просмотра фото.

Проблема заключается в том, что фото открывается в первоначальном размере (больше окна программы) и если в него (окно) фото не помещается, то просто обрезается.

Мне нужно чтобы фото открывалось уменьшенным (скажем **`700х500`**), как это сделать?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.04alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window['bg'] = 'grey'

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
#img
pil_image = Image.open("C:/111.jpg")

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8)

label_pic_name = Label(window, text='<< lena.jpg >>')                           
label_pic_name.grid(row=2, column=1)                            

#bottons_top
frame_top = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn4.grid(row=0, column=4)

#bottons_side
frame_side = Frame(window)
frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
btn11 = Button(frame_side, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn22 = Button(frame_side, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn22.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             
             )
btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn44.grid(row=4, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.04alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window['bg'] = 'grey'

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
#img
pil_image = Image.open("image_test2.jpg")          

pil_image = pil_image.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)            # <----

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8)

label_pic_name = Label(window, text='<< image_test2.jpg >>')                           
label_pic_name.grid(row=2, column=1)                            

#bottons_top
frame_top = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",            
             )
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             padx=5
             )
btn4.grid(row=0, column=4)

#bottons_side
frame_side = Frame(window)
frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
btn11 = Button(frame_side, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn22 = Button(frame_side, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn22.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             
             )
btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
            
             )
btn44.grid(row=4, column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**image_test2.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]